# Getting coordinates ASCII file?

Tags: coordinate-system, arcgis-pro, latitude-longitude

[image]

I want latitude longitude information as an ASCII file for a location of my choice in 1 km resolution. The picture shows data for each grid point. Now I want the lat long info for each grid, also as an Ascii file. How do I get it?

Comment: Welcome to GIS SE. As a new user, please take the [Tour]. Your problem statement needs clarification. It would help if you can give more details about the ASCII files -- especially whether they represent vector or raster data.  I would point out that it is a relatively simple process to generate an ASCII file from the contents of a vector table (with or without having run AddXY), so if you're having difficulty with the arcpy code to do this, you should provide the code you have attempted, with a description of the problem encountered.

Comment: Can you include the first few lines in your question... not the very long ones, just the short lines; there are a few formats that are called ASCII and the header information will assist with this. You also have Desktop and Pro tags for your question, which platform do you prefer or is either equally as good?